# Does Dropbox have a built in version control system?

Tags: sync, dropbox

I want to know this if I have files on my desktop which is then synced with Dropbox.

I accidentally deleted all files from my desktop folder (which is synced with Dropbox) now will my files from Dropbox be deleted as well? Or does Dropbox still have the old files?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sort of - dropbox will keep backups up to 30 days on free accounts - which you can  to [restore from](http://www.dropbox.com/help/11) the dropbox [webpage](http://www.dropbox.com). The 'paid' versions have unlimited rollback.

you could also try the [cache](http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=1917)

Comment: Dropbox actually keeps previous versions for 30 days on the free accounts.

Comment: The “unlimited rollback” is actually an add-on feature called [Pack-Rat or Rewind](https://www.dropbox.com/help/113) (the name changes depending on the type of account: Pro or Team).